# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING

Tags: java, json, arraylist, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a REST service built with Jersey and deployed in the AppEngine. The REST service implements the verb PUT that consumes an `application/json` media type. The data binding is performed by Jackson.

The verb consumes an enterprise-departments relation represented in JSON as

```
{"name":"myEnterprise", "departments":["HR","IT","SC"]}
```

On the client side, I use gson to convert the JSON representation into a java object. Then, I pass the object to my REST service and it works fine.

**Problem:**

When my JSON representation has only one item in the collection

```
{"name":"myEnterprise", "departments":["HR"]}
```

the service cannot deserialize the object.

```
ATTENTION: /enterprise/enterprise: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token at 
[Source: org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser$Input@5a9c5842; line: 1, column: 2
```

As reported by other users, the solution is to add the flag `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` (e.g., [Jersey: Can not deserialize instance of ArrayList out of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319573/jersey-can-not-deserialize-instance-of-arraylist-out-of-string)). Nevertheless, I am not controlling an `ObjectMapper` because in the service side it is transparently made by Jackson.

**Question:**

Is there a way to configure the `ObjectMapper` on the service side to enable `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`? annotations? `web.xml`?

**Code details**

Java object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Enterprise {
    private String name;
    private List<String> departments;

    public Enterprise() {}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<String> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }
    public void setDepartments(List<String> departments) {
        this.departments = departments;
    }
}
```

The REST service side:

```
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/enterprise") 
    public Response putEnterprise(Enterprise enterprise,
            @Context HttpServletRequest req){
         ...
    }
```

Client side:

```
...
String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"myEnterprise\", \"departments\":[\"HR\"]}";
Enterprise enterprise = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Enterprise.class);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(enterprise));
response = webResource              
           .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
           .put(ClientResponse.class,enterprise);
if (response.getStatus() >= 400) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
}
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackson deserialization - with contained ArrayList<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978748/jackson-deserialization-with-contained-arraylistt)

Comment: I agree. Probably it is the same. However, here my concrete question is how to set the ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY flag if I am not managing the ObjectMapper… if possible.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is the solution for my old question:

I implemented my own `ContextResolver` in order to enable the `DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` feature.

```
package org.lig.hadas.services.mapper;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{
   ObjectMapper mapper;

   public ObjectMapperProvider(){
       mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
   }
   @Override
   public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
       return mapper;
   }
}
```

And in the `web.xml` I registered my package into the servlet definition...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>...</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>...;org.lig.hadas.services.mapper</param-value>        
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```

... all the rest is transparently done by jersey/jackson.

Comment: new version: `objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);`

Answer (score 30):

Setting this attribute to ObjectMapper instance works,

```
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
```

Comment: His question was how to set that flag without access to the ObjectManager.

Answer (score 25):

do you try

```
[{"name":"myEnterprise", "departments":["HR"]}]
```

the square brace is the key point.

Comment: The problem was in "departments" level. This is a particularity of jackson and I solved it by creating my own ContextResolver

Answer (score 19):

from Jackson 2.7.x+ there is a way to annotate the member variable itself:

```java
 @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
 private List<String> newsletters;
```

More info here: [Jackson @JsonFormat](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Feature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)

Answer (score 6):

For people that find this question by searching for the error message, you can also see this error if you make a mistake in your `@JsonProperty` annotations such that you annotate a `List`-typed property with the name of a single-valued field:

```
@JsonProperty("someSingleValuedField") // Oops, should have been "someMultiValuedField"
public List<String> getMyField() { // deserialization fails - single value into List
  return myField;
}
```

Comment: isn't "deserialization" utilizing setters and not the getter? Getter is accessed during serialization as far as I know

Comment: deserialization may use the setter or reflection, but the annotation by convention is on the getter from what I recall