# Jackson: how to read a String as List?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Our current class looks like

```
public class Attributes {

  private String mapping;

  .....
```

and

```
{
  "mapping": "displayName",
  .....
```

This has worked well and shipped to customers.

The way we convert `JSON` to `Attribute` class is

```
JSON.readValue(jsonFile, Attribute.class);
```

Recently the requirement says, that `mapping` would be `List<String>` instead of `String`

At first, the quick change that I thought of was to change `mapping` to `List<String>`, but this would break existing clients.

I tried that by writing test that does

```
assertEquals("displayName", configuration.getMapping().get(0));
```

and it failed as

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
```

**Question**
How can I tell `Jackson` to read a `String` as `List? It would be List of 1 item but would be backward compatible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588727/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-util-arraylist-out-of-value-string)

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```