# Jackson Object Mapper in Spring not working

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have Spring MVC app which receives JSON POSTed from Javascript frontend.
Using Jackson 2, custom object mapper only to set ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY as true.
Below is my code snippet.

Enable MVC Java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(0, jackson2Converter());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2Converter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String submitForm(@RequestBody final Shipment shipment) { 
...
}
```

POJO:

```
  class Shipment implements Serializable { 

    private String dstState;
    private List<String> dstCities;
    // getters, setters and default constructor
    }
```

Ajax POST call:

```
$.ajax({ url: ".../home", type: "POST", data: JSON.stringify(("#shipForm").serializeArray()), contentType: "application/json", dataType: 'json', ....
```

JSON object posted: mydata: {"dstState":"NV" ,"dstCities":"Las Vegas"}

Upon receiving POST, there is error:

```
Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@44733b90; line: 1, column: 90] (through reference chain: com.*.Shipment["dstCities"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
```

Please point to anything I am missing here

Comment: Show the rest which will send

Comment: JSON object posted:
mydata: {"dstState":"NV" ,"dstCities":"Las Vegas"}

$.ajax({
        url: ".../home",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(("#logdForm").serializeArray()),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        ....

Comment: Will this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588727/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-util-arraylist-out-of-value-string

Comment: @JamesJithin Pointed question was for javax.ws.rs and Codehaus jackson
and I am not using Provider annotations :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You input json data format is incorrect.

**`Shipment` Json Representation:**

- `Shipment` is Json object
- `String dstState` is also Json object
- `List<String> dstCities` is Json Array

Correct Json Data format for your `Shipment` class is like

```
 [{"dstState":"NV" , "dstCities": ["Las Vegas"]}]
```

or

```
[{"dstState":"NV" , "dstCities": ["Las Vegas", "Las Not Vegas"]}]
```