# ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT with List field

Tags: java, json, jackson

with Jackson, I'm trying to properly deserialize a JSON which contains empty string as *no value* values. Herein an example:

```
{
  "code" : "REQ500",
  "description" : "Problem with Service",
  "params" : ""
}
```

and the bean I would get:

```
public final class MyError {

    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;

    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty("params")
    private List<String> params;

    // [CUT]

    public void setParams(List<String> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

Using [ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features#value-conversions-coercion), I've create an object mapper with

```
public static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper()
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true)
    .registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new DateDeserializer()));
```

expecting to have `params = null`, but deserialization doesn't work. Herein the error I got:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot 
deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "code" : "REQ500",
  "description" : "Problem with Service",
  "params" : ""
}"; line: 4, column: 14] (through reference chain: solutions.infinitec.fabrick.models.common.MyError["params"])

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
```

Any hints on how to solve this issue? Am I wrong somewhere?

Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Comment: did u try with implement setter method?

Comment: Yep, implemented. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it using `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` and it works as expected.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

MyJson asString = om.readValue("{\n"
            + "  \"code\" : \"REQ500\",\n"
            + "  \"description\" : \"Problem with Service\",\n"
            + "  \"params\" : \"\"\n"
            + "}", MyError.class);

MyJson asArray = om.readValue("{\n"
            + "  \"code\" : \"REQ500\",\n"
            + "  \"description\" : \"Problem with Service\",\n"
            + "  \"params\" : [\"\"]\n"
            + "}", MyError.class);
```

The only thing you have to handle is the response containing just a single element in params which is empty.

Another way could be this definition of `MyError`:

```
public class MyError {

    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;

    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;

    private List<String> params;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    @JsonProperty("params")
    private void setParams(JsonNode params) {
        if (params.isArray()) {
            this.params = new ArrayList<>();
            for(JsonNode child : params) {
                this.params.add(child.asText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a setter method which accept string:

```
public void setParams(String params) {
    this.params = null;
}
```

if want to accept array:

```
public void setParams(String[] params) {
    this.params = Arrays.asList(params);
}
```

Comment: when jackson deserialize it call no argument construct if there is no jsoncreator constructor. then call setter method.

Comment: u need to implement another method which accept array

Comment: Herein the error: `line: 4, column: 13] (through reference chain: solutions.infinitec.fabrick.models.common.MyError["params"])`

Comment: Doesn't work. I've got the following error: `Cannot deserialize instance of 'java.lang.String' out of START_ARRAY token`.

Comment: Interesting solution proposed by Halko Karr-Sajtarevic solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using

```
OBJECT_MAPPER.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
```

As shown in ["Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588727/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-util-arraylist-out-of-value-string)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain how this API solves the problem.

Comment: Already tried, it doesn't solve my issue given that, unfortunately, `ObjectMapper::enable` has the same behaviour of configuring `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY ` equal to `true`.